# Save python nested list with string literals included tokens to file delimited by tab

Tags: python, list, save, nested-lists, string-literals

I want to store a python nested list like that:

```
document_list = [['This', 'is', 'the', 'title', '\n\n\n\n', 'Rest', 'of', 
  'the', 'first', 'document'], ['Second', 'Document', '\t', 'title', '\n\n\n\n']]
```

How I can save the list taking each word as raw string?
I tried sth like that:

```
with open('doc_list.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join(doc) + '\n' for doc in document_list)
```

But then it naturally doesn't writes the string literals as raw strings.
Has somebody any idea how I could fix this? Thanks!

UPDATE: My expected output-textfile should look like this:

```
This   is   the   title   \n\n\n\n   Rest   of   the   first   document
Second   Document   \t   title   \n\n\n\n
```

There is always a tab-space btw two words..

Comment: can you please write expected output?

Answer (score 0):

this will create 2 files and stores it in to document0.txt and document1.txt

```
document_list = [['This', 'is', 'the', 'title', '\n\n\n\n', 'Rest', 'of',
                  'the', 'first', 'document'], ['Second', 'Document', '\t', 'title', '\n\n\n\n']]

doc = [' '.join(i) for i in document_list]
for i in range(0, len(doc)):
    with open('document' + str(i) + '.txt', 'w') as f:
      f.write(doc[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write as JSON ?

```
import json

document_list = [['This', 'is', 'the', 'title', '\n\n\n\n', 'Rest', 'of',
              'the', 'first', 'document'], ['Second', 'Document', '\t', 
              'title', '\n\n\n\n']]
with open('doc_list.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(document_list))
```